# Problema laravel y http post con payu

Tags: laravel, post, payu

Estoy integrando el `webcheckout` de payu y necesito almacenar informacion con la pagina de confirmacion de payu, que me envia datos por HTTP post.

El problema es que cuando termino la transaccion no estoy recibiendo los datos de forma adecuada (creo), pues el form con esa informacion no llega a mi método.

Puse un archivo para verificar los datos que llegan de payu a mi pagina y efectivamente estan llegando, pero cuando intento enviarlos a mi metodo usando una ruta post y utilizando el metodo request no llega nada adjunto imagenes del codigo:

[image: Formulario enviado a payU]

[image: Ruta de http post]

Funcion de recibir y guardar:

[image: recibir]

Informacion que llega de payU

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Me perdí a partir de "(creo) el form con esa informacion no llega a mi metodo, puse un archivo para verificar los datos que llegan de payu a mi pagina y efectivamente estan llegando"... ¿si llegan los datos o no llegan?

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya encontré la solución, estaba recibiendo mal los datos que llegaban de payU, no debe usarse como tipo Request $request, únicamente utilizar $_Request['state_pol']; de igual manera gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Ah, ya te entendí, pues si, en tu última captura viene que dice que es un array lo que te está llegando y no un objeto, por lo tanto si debes de ocupar los corchetes.